# Amazon WorkSpaces client "unable to connect" error message after login screen

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workspaces

WorkSpaces client is showing the above error message after giving credentials in loginscreen and clicking on login.

```
Amazon WorkSpaces

Unable to connect
We couldn't launch your WorkSpace. Please try again.
If you need help, contact your administrator.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response John.Let me give you few more insights on this- we have recently migrated to Amazon workspaces from Citrix in my organization, first week I had no issues with Amazon workspaces and after that I started getting the above error message and our support team had rebuilt my workspace from their end and they said, the issue could have resolved but no success in my case. I am attaching link to a folder which contains the screenshots of messages that I am getting while logging in.Please suggest a solution. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1CWIwht_Oh8kJwVfAmbxqzOmaVd-sRmzL

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be using Amazon WorkSpaces.

The error is saying that the nominated WorkSpace either does not exist, or there is a problem launching it.

You should **look in the Amazon WorkSpaces management console** to check the instance. If somebody else setup WorkSpaces for you, it is possible that you do not have enough permissions to look at this information. That is why the error message is suggests that you should contact your administrator.

Comment: Thanks for the response John.Let me give you few more insights on this- we have recently migrated to Amazon workspaces from Citrix in my organization, first week I had no issues with Amazon workspaces and after that I started getting the above error message and our support team had rebuilt my workspace from their end and they said, the issue could have resolved but no success in my case. I am attaching link to a folder which contains the screenshots of messages that I am getting while logging in.Please suggest a solution. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1CWIwht_Oh8kJwVfAmbxqzOmaVd-sRmzL

Comment: The problem lies either with the provisioning of the WorkSpace, or the contents of the WorkSpace disk (eg not booting up correctly). There is nothing that you as a "user" can do. Your admins will need to re-provision the WorkSpace, possibly from a "clean" image. You'll need to work with them, since as a "user" you have no access to any configuration settings.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue a few times. Restarting the workspace (which takes around 5-10 minutes) and then logging in again worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just have the Administrator reboot or stop on the Workspace console, it takes about 5min though, All the time i have experienced it its when there has been a network disruption.

Answer (score 0):

Also, be aware that there is a Running Mode setting on the WorkSpaces console for the WorkSpace. If set to AutoStop, and set with a time period, it will be stopped automatically after the being idle for that period of time. Setting it to AlwaysOn will ensure it stays active, but beware that you'll move to a monthly billing model, not by-the-minute.